# Can a web service call another web service in the same application server

Tags: java, web-services, java-metro-framework

I'm using Netbeans 6.5 to generate the JAX-WS Metro service and Glassfish 2.1 as the application server.

Assume I have two web services e.g.

...

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "doXXX")
public String doXXX(
@WebParam(name = "id") String id
...    

...
@WebMethod(operationName = "doYYY")
public String doYYY(
@WebParam(name = "result") String result
...
```

and I have a Web Service client (a Java application) that happily calls both.

I now want method XXX to call method YYY i.e. I need to place the client proxy for YYY inside of web service XXX.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around and figured it out.

You don't want to call the actual web service via a proxy client because then you will needlessly serialize / deserialize the data.

Assume in the example above, that the doXXX method is inside a class called XXX and that the doYYY method is inside a class called YYY.

(Note that the class would be annotated by a @WebService() tag.)

To call doYYY() from the doXXX method:

```
YYY yyy = new YYY ();  
yyy.doYYY ();
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't attempt to proxy a request to invoke a method inside the same application - this will incur needless serialization/deserialization of Objects to XML messages and back.

If you need to call another method inside the same application, re-design your application so that you can gain access to whatever area of the application you need to invoke.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do that? Remember the two web services still have to be able to be called externally. Can I simply add doYYY() to XXX?

Comment: Something along those lines, yes.